# Show Android Spinner as a Drop Down?

Tags: android

Is there any way to actually show the Spinner as a Drop Down the way it is shown here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

I can only get the default modal dialog that's centered over the entire screen.

Using API 8, and my implementation is essentially the same as what is shown in the above link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend learning the QuickActionWidget and extending it to do this job, here's a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833621/custom-spinners-drop-down-menu) asked on StackOverflow, i think the answer there is what you need. You might need to do some editing to the code and design, but the basic idea is the same.

Comment: That specifically is what the OP said they are *not* interested in ("the default modal dialog that's centered over the entire screen").