# android custom spinner with dropdown option showing below spinner

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I want to create a custom spinner,where the dropdown option will be shown below the spinner itself like the dropdown listbox in webservice.But i could only able to change the color and textcolor of spinner and could not achieve it.Is there any possibility to achieve this,because now options were shown in middle of screen which doesn't looks good.

```
My android version is 2.3.7
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this link [custom spinners drop down menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833621/custom-spinners-drop-down-menu).

Comment: how to import **QuickActionWidget** there ?

Comment: Here you can find example [QuickAction](https://github.com/alhneiti/Android-QuickAction).