# Android how to create overlay drop-down menu similar to Google+ app

Tags: android

I am attempting to create a drop-down menu like the one found in the Google+ app. A screenshot can be found below. I have looked at Spinners and Popup Menus, but neither of these fit exactly for what I am trying to create. The first image shows the closed menu, and the second shows what the drop-down menu looks like when opened.

http://www.droid-life.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/google-plus-4.4-1.jpg

The menu should not appear inside the action bar, and when scrolling, the menu displaying the selected option remains at the top of the screen.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9847763/3864698

Comment: I did look at that example and many others; however, I was unable to find an example in which the menu was scrollable, the choice would remain overlaid at the top, and was as wide as the screen.

Comment: Have you found some kind of solution? I faced with the same task

Comment: @konunger I have not. Unfortunately, the best alternative I could come up with was just placing the spinner inside the action bar.

Comment: @DonnieAdams, I'm working on custom solution, I think it'l take 2-3 days

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have enough reputation to add comments, So I'll post as an answer, hope it'll help anybody. This is just my alternative solution trying to achieve a ui like google plus app as you've posted.

My current solution is to use a toolbar beneath the actionbar(which is a toolbar also set as actionbar). Then I add onClickListener for the toolbar. When the toolbar is tapped, a recyclerview will be visible. Which the recyclerview can be populate by dynamic data or custom data you put in the layout. Example code :

main_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout .... >

// the actionbar toolbar
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
 android:id="@+id/action_toolbar"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        app:theme="@style/toolbarStyle"/>

// second toolbar act as the spinner
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
 android:id="@+id/dropdown_toolbar"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
 style="@style/dropdownToolbar">

..... // add a spinner indicator (imageview)

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

//separator line
<View
 android:id="@+id/separator_line"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="1dp"
 android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
 android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
 android:background="#adacad"/>

// two child overlaps in framelayout
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white">

// the visible layout example
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/default_recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

// the layout that is visible when toolbar is tapped
// this is spinner content, put anything u want here
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/dropdown_recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This will give u a full width and length layout. the dropdown_recyclerview content depends on what u want. I added an imageview to indicate if the fake spinner is open or close. Sample code for java :

MainActivity.java

```
//action toolbar
Toolbar actionToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.action_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(actionToolbar);

RecyclerView dropdownRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.dropdown_recyclerview);

//second toolbar
Toolbar dropdownToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.dropdown_toolbar);

//Listen for toolbar onClick
dropdownToolbar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
//toggle visibility of dropdown spinner
  if (!SHOW_SPINNER_FLAG) {

//set indicator close / open
  dropdownRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {

//set indicator close / open
dropdownRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     } 
   }
});
```

Later on you can customized the layout and add some animation to reveal the fake spinner layout. If there's other way, please share. For the moment this is what i use in my app and it works fine for me. Sorry for my poor english.

[example app image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhp8A.png)

Comment: You can inspect the Google+ app through UIAutomatorViewer (In your sdk/tools folder).  What they are doing isn't very different from what you've done.  The drop down menu is a RelativeLayout (So the buttons can be at the bottom) with a ListView.