# Adding separators between groups of actionbar menu items

Tags: java, android, menu, android-actionbar

I'm creating an android action bar menu for an app. What I'm looking for is a way to show the logical groupings of menu items. So what I have currently is:

[image]

Whereas what I'd like is:

[image]

I'm creating the menu as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    //Note, on 2.3.x - 3.0 this is called when user opens the menu for the first timed
    //on 3.0+ it is called when the activity starts

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    //adds the (currently empty) menu, after login it will be filled with options
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    menu.add("example");
    menu.add("example");
    return true;
}
```

Menu XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:compat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    >
</menu>
```

I had hoped menu groups would help, but I understand that they are just for modifying all the menu items properties together. Equally, submenu actually creates a hidden menu that is opened free-floating when clicked.

Is there any way to create this logical grouping of menu items that I'm looking for?

Comment: Unless you do use reflection to change the menu list from the system I don't think there's a way to do what you want. If you really want to have those separators you could implement the menu yourself as a popup(but I don't think it's worth the hassle).

Comment: @Luksprog Thats a shame. It seemed like such standard behaviour

Comment: Try this : make your each menu item to have a textview and a black dark horizontal bar, then when you inflate your menu, hide the black dark bar for the cases where you don't want it. This should make such a grouping.

Comment: @Abhinav That's quite an interesting idea.I'll give it a go on monday

Comment: I know its late but, if still needed, try this answer : `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833621/custom-spinners-drop-down-menu`, I found it when I tried the same thing as yours